# Spring Integration with Spring Boot run as war

Tags: tomcat, spring-boot, spring-integration, dsl

I am trying to run my Spring Integration app with Spring Boot in tomcat (so I am packaging it as war).

I am able to successfully deploy the war but it's not listening for messages on a given queue. Everything works fine when I start it as an application within the IDE. 
Can someone point me what am I missing in the following code or if that should be deployed in a different way?

```
@Configuration
@SpringBootApplication
@IntegrationComponentScan
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@EnableIntegration
public class SpringIntegrationApplication {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(SpringIntegrationApplication .class, args);
}

@Autowired
private ActiveMQConnectionFactory activeMQConnectionFactory;

@Bean
public IntegrationFlow jmsInboundFlow() {
    return IntegrationFlows.from(
                                Jms.inboundAdapter(this.activeMQConnectionFactory)
                                                    .configureJmsTemplate(t -> t.deliveryPersistent(true)/*.jmsMessageConverter(myMessageConverter())*/)
                                                    .destination("testQueue"), // name of the queue
                                e -> e.poller( Pollers.fixedDelay(10000).maxMessagesPerPoll(20) )
                             )
                             .enrich(e -> e
                                    .requestPayload(Message::getPayload)
                                    .shouldClonePayload(false)                                                                               
                                    .<Map<String, String>>headerFunction("originalMessage", m -> m.getPayload(), true)
                             )
                             .channel("entrypoint")
                             .get();
}

@Router(inputChannel="entrypoint")
public String route(@SuppressWarnings("rawtypes") Message message) {

    if (isErrorMessage) {
        return "done.input";
    }
```

}

And this gradle (build.gradle) packages it:

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'war'
apply plugin: 'maven-publish'

version = '1.0-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = 1.8
targetCompatibility = 1.8
repositories {
 mavenCentral()
}


dependencies {

compile(
    [group: 'org.springframework.integration', name: 'spring-integration-feed', version: springframeworkVersion],
    'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:1.3.3.RELEASE',
    'org.springframework.integration:spring-integration-core:4.2.5.RELEASE',
    'org.springframework.integration:spring-integration-flow:1.0.0.RELEASE',
    'org.springframework.integration:spring-integration-java-dsl:1.1.2.RELEASE',
    'org.springframework.integration:spring-integration-http:4.2.5.RELEASE',
    'org.springframework.integration:spring-integration-jms:4.2.5.RELEASE', 
    'org.springframework.integration:spring-integration-jdbc:4.2.5.RELEASE',
    [group: 'log4j', name: 'log4j', version: '1.2.17'],
    [group: 'org.slf4j', name: 'slf4j-log4j12', version: '1.7.5'],
    [group: 'javax.servlet', name: 'jstl', version: '1.2'],         
    [group: 'org.apache.activemq', name: 'activemq-amqp', version: '5.13.3'],
    'javax:javaee-api:7.0'
)

//If more required then 
//http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.integration

testCompile (
    [group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.11'],
    [group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-test', version: '1.3.5.RELEASE'] 
)

}
```

Any input highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wonder if you have in your application a `SpringBootServletInitializer`: http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-create-a-deployable-war-file.

Otherwise, please, share DEBUG logs for `org.springframework` after starting your application in the Tomcat.